# Rails form_tag redirect route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I have a form_tag that I want to go to a certain action of the controller that I implemented:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "admins", :action => "check_in") do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work, it redirects to admins/check_in a correct route thai is the one I want to redirect but rails puts "No route matches "/admins/check_in"" error. I don't understand, because this route is correct if I put in the browser "http://localhost:3000/admins/check_in" it works. How can I correct it to redirect admins controller check_in action??

Comment: Is it GET or POST action in route?

Comment: we need to see your check_in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a case of using GET for the route and POST upon form submission.
If you run `rake routes` you should see the route is a GET, right? When a form submits it makes a POST request. Either make the form_tag like this:

```
form_tag({:controller => "admins", :action => "check_in"}, :method => "get")
```

or change the route to POST in the routes.rb file like so:

```
post "admins/check_in" => "admins#check_in"
```

You can see, when you start rails with `rails s` in the terminal, what kind of request it receives by reading the request log as it comes in.

Hope that helps, otherwise:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks I forgot to put :method => "get" in the form_tag, this works perfectly.